# Linear regression with outliers for Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Python (jupyter notebook to be exact), using `numpy` and `sklearn` only

```
np.random.seed(16)
x = np.arange(100) 
yp = 3*x + 3 + 2*(np.random.poisson(3*x+3,100)-(3*x+3))
np.random.seed(12)
# Choose how many outliers
out = np.random.choice(100,15)
yp_wo = np.copy(yp)
np.random.seed(12) #set again
yp_wo[out] = yp_wo[out] + 5*np.random.rand(15)*yp[out]
# With outliers
plt.scatter(x,yp_wo)
# Without outliers
plt.scatter(x,yp)
```

For the data above (`wo` means "with outliers"), I need to find:

- The best coefficients for two more losses: the MAE and the MAPE (Median Absolute Percentage Error)
- Plot the best fit line for the MSE loss, the MAE loss, and the MAPE loss.
- Apply Ridge Regression to the same data, and use cross validation to choose the optimal parameter alpha (you can use values of alpha = 10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, ... 10^3). Which value gives you the lowest MSE?

What confuses me is having to plot the best line fit for *two or more losses*.

I can follow the code from class and try to get the values, but I don't know what's meant by coefficients.

Any help / guidance?

This is for a homework I am trying to figure out (no I am not asking for the solutions)

Please excuse any formatting errors, I am very new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: in `3*x + 3`, the first 3 is a coefficient which tells you the slope of the regressed line and the second 3 is the y-intercept i.e. the value that y takes when x is zero. so, basically when you use different losses you will end up with different values of these two variables (slope aka coefficient  and y-intercept aka constant). Does this help?

Comment: If actually about the underlying concepts rather than about the code itself, this question might be better suited for [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com) (or another SE site) instead of SO.

Comment: @sai Right, but do I just build the model to get said losses?

Comment: Sounds a bit like an assignment. Is it?

Comment: Losses are independent of models. You can use any loss you want(for testing). But, the loss which you use during building determines your model-